# Understanding SharedPreference behavior using Mockito

Tags: android, junit, mocking, sharedpreferences, mockito

I have problems testing on mock objects, especially on my self-written class as well as on SharedPreferences mock. I extracted a code snippet from the app I am involved in and simplified it for understanding what is going on.

I have the following gradle settings within my project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.mk_xappo.mockitoexample"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

And I have got this class here:

```
package de.mk_xappo.mockitoexample;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;


public class FeedbackManager {

    protected static final String RATED = "RATED";

    private final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


    public FeedbackManager(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
        this.sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
    }

    protected void setRated() {
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(RATED, true).commit();
    }

    protected boolean getRated() {
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(RATED, false);
    }

    protected static boolean getTrue() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean getFalse() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I have this test class:

```
package de.mk_xappo.mockitoexample;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyBoolean;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyLong;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class FeedbackManagerTest {

    private Application applicationMock;
    private SharedPreferences preferencesMock;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editorMock;
    private FeedbackManager feedbackManager;

    @org.junit.Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        applicationMock = mock(Application.class);
        preferencesMock = mock(SharedPreferences.class);

        when(applicationMock.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(preferencesMock);

        editorMock = mock(SharedPreferences.Editor.class);

        when(editorMock.putBoolean(anyString(), anyBoolean())).thenReturn(editorMock);
        when(editorMock.putLong(anyString(), anyLong())).thenReturn(editorMock);
        when(editorMock.remove(anyString())).thenReturn(editorMock);
        when(preferencesMock.edit()).thenReturn(editorMock);

//        feedbackManager = new FeedbackManager(preferencesMock);
        feedbackManager = mock(FeedbackManager.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBoolean() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertTrue(FeedbackManager.getTrue());
        Assert.assertFalse(feedbackManager.getFalse());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetRated() throws Exception {
        boolean rated = feedbackManager.getRated();
        Assert.assertFalse(rated);
        feedbackManager.setRated();

        rated = feedbackManager.getRated();

        when(preferencesMock.getBoolean(FeedbackManager.RATED, false)).thenReturn(false);
        when(preferencesMock.getBoolean(FeedbackManager.RATED, false)).thenReturn(true);

        Assert.assertFalse(rated);
        Assert.assertTrue(rated);
    }
}
```

Now, what I do not understand is that if I run `testBoolean()` everything works as expected. But If I run `testSetRated()` two things do **not** work as expected.

Because **neither** `when(preferencesMock.getBoolean(FeedbackManager.RATED, false)).thenReturn(false);` **nor** `when(preferencesMock.getBoolean(FeedbackManager.RATED, false)).thenReturn(true);` fails though they are contrary.

And I don't understand why `Assert.assertFalse(rated);` **works** and `Assert.assertTrue(rated);` **fails**. This shall be the other way round.

Maybe I misunderstand the usage of mocks, especially SharedPreferences mocks? Or what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I really misunderstood how `when(mock.method()).thenReturn(value)` works. It does not check anything. It only says that the `mock` object shall return `value` if `method()` is called the next time. The `testSetRated()` method can also be tested by looking if `SharedPreferences` have been written. Then everything works as expected.